# LWIP: When to deallocate the pbuf after calling udp_sendto(...)?

Tags: lwip

When sending a UDP packet with LWIP using the uds_sendto(...) call when do I deallocate the pbuf? Can I do this right after uds_sendto(...) or do I have to wait for the paket to actually having been sent to the network and then do this in some callback?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deallocate the pbuf immediately after calling udp_sendto, unless you're doing something fancy like [Zero-Copy TX buffers](https://community.nxp.com/t5/LPCware-Archive-Content/LWIP-buffer-management/ta-p/1110512)